# How to interpret summation convention?

Tags: summation, physics, mathematical-physics

In Landau and Lifschitz Mechanics, p. 99, we have (implicit) the equality $$\Omega_i^2 x_i^2 = \Omega_i \Omega_k \delta_{ik} x_{\ell}^2 $$ written with Einstein summation convention.

The left hand side is clearly: $$\Omega_1^2x_1^2 + \Omega_2^2x_2^2+ \Omega_3^2x_3^2 $$

The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377231/einstein-summation-with-multiple-terms) would indicate that the right hand side should be interpreted this way:

$$\Omega_i\Omega_k\delta_{ik}x_{\ell}^2 = \sum_i\sum_k \left[\Omega_i \Omega_k \delta_{ik} \left[\sum_{\ell}  x_{\ell}^2 \right] \right]  \\= \Omega_1^2[x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2] + \Omega_2^2[x_1^2 + x_2^2+x_3^2] + \Omega_3^2[x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2]$$

However, I only get that this is an identity when I interpret it this way:

$$\Omega_i\Omega_k\delta_{ik}x_{\ell}^2 = \sum_i\sum_k\sum_{\ell} \Omega_i\Omega_k\delta_{ik}x_{\ell}^2 = \Omega_1^2x_1^2 + \Omega_2^2x_2^2+ \Omega_3^2x_3^2   $$

So is there a mistake in the textbook? Or is the answer given to the other question incorrect? I've tried googling this, but all of the examples given are single terms, not multiple terms.

**EDIT:** The full equation in the textbook is (if it helps): $$\Omega_i^2 x_i^2 - \Omega_i x_i \Omega_k x_k = \Omega_i \Omega_k \delta_{ik} x_{\ell}^2 - \Omega_i \Omega_k x_i x_k $$

[image]

Comment: Using your latter intrepretation, you still got $$\Omega_1^2[x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2] + \Omega_2^2[x_1^2 + x_2^2+x_3^2] + \Omega_3^2[x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2]$$

Comment: Why do you have $x^2_\ell$ in the first equation $\Omega_i^2 x_i^2 = \Omega_i \Omega_k \delta_{ik} x_{\ell}^2$? Is the $\ell$ index a typo?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is based on a false premise.

Comment: No it's not a typo -- that's how it is in the textbook.

Comment: You can delete your own question, you don't need to vote to close. (Actually i am a bit confused by the convention in the book - repeated indices are summed, but what about $\Omega_i^2 x_i^2 = \Omega_i \Omega_i x_i x_i$, which has $4$ i's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is unclear what is the expression

$$\Omega_i^2 x_i^2$$

as there are indeed $4$ i's in the expression. But after reading previous page of the book, this term corresponds to

$$\Omega ^2 r^2 = (\Omega \cdot \Omega)(r\cdot r)$$

so the expression should be written as

$$ \Omega_i^2 x_l^2$$

instead.